# opencv + скриншот real-time

Tags: python, циклы, opencv, screenshots

Многие видели, как разработчики натравливаю ***.py на камеру и в итоге получают отдельное окно (frame) где в секунду отображается 20+ кадров.
Я понимаю, что эти кадры это быстроменяющиеся скриншоты поданные с камеры. Как натравить такой код на какое-либо окно в windows?
Аналог - боты для игр. Им скармливают pid процесса и далее они анализирую все что нужно и инициализируют действия.
У меня ситуация аналогичная - найти pid и переключиться на него - сделано.
Создать скриншот - готово

Кусок кода

```
import pyscreeze
import time
import cv2


while True:
    pyscreeze.screenshot('1.png', region=(0, 0, 300, 400))
    img = cv2.imread("1.png")
    cv2.imshow("image.png", img)
    print('1')
    time.sleep(2)
```

В этом куске кода, я скриню часть рабочей области экрана. Но, созданное окно "image.png" не прогружается. Т.е. серый фон (даже если sleep поставить 5 секунд). В то время, если в этом же цикле добавить cv2.waitkey(0), то изображение грузится, но приходится каждый проход нажимать клавишу(но сам скрин грузится мгновенно).

Возможно я вообще не в ту сторону пошел. Но пока не понял, как реализовать нормальный (15+ fps) скриншотинг.

Если это необходимо - дополню. К каждому скрину далее будут применяться фильтры и вызываться команды при нахождении паттерна изображения.